# jQuery - Warning division by zero

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I get this error:

```
Warning: Division by zero in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/xxxxx/xxxx/login.php on line 497
```

The thing is that line 497 in the login.php file looks like this:

```
";
```

and nothing else. (I'm closing a php echo function.

I think the problem lies with my jQuery function, which looks like this (and which works in a standard HTML page):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#progressBar').progressbar({
             value: 0
         });
});
var statusTracker;
var percentage = 1;

function checkStatus() {
    percentage += 1;
    $('.green span').text(percentage + "%");
    $('.green').width(percentage + '%');

    if (percentage == 100) stop();

}
function startProgress(){
    statusTracker = setInterval(checkStatus, 100);
}

function stop() {
    clearInterval(statusTracker);
}
$(document).ready(startProgress);  
</script>
```

I can't seem to find the problem. Help will be very appreciated!

**EDIT: When I remove the jQuery function above, the PHP error is also gone.**

Comment: jQuery wont throw php errors.

Comment: The error produced by PHP so the error is in your PHP code. Please add it , or at least lines 490 - 500.

Comment: When I remove the jQuery function I wrote, the error is gone.

Comment: is your <script> inside <?php ?

Comment: @j_mcnally yes, the script is inside the php tags.

Comment: try changing `value: 0` to `value: 1`

Comment: Throw the JavaScript code and show us the function that line 497 is a part of.

Comment: I noticed you're closing the echo string (which is obviously multiline) with a double quote. Try escaping your newlines, or using single quotes.

Comment: I already tried changing value: 0 to value: 1 - didn't change a thing.
@Jonast92 the javascript code is posted in my original post. Line 497 is just "; like described in my post.

Comment: Can you points us at the `progressBar` library/script?

Comment: move the script outside of your php tag. why does it need to be? this will almost certainly cause errors.

Comment: @oliverbj it doesn't matter if line 497 only has `";`, it is obviously something before that that is causing the error. Show us the entire echo, because if any line of your string contains the error, it only gets evaluated on the line on which you CLOSE the string.

Comment: @Asad This actually worked. Thanks a lot! Can I get the reason why it's like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your script outside of `<?php ?>`

there is no reason for it to be in there... i am guessing that is even invalid.

if it must be inside php tags do the following

```
echo <<<EOD

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#progressBar').progressbar({
             value: 0
         });
});
var statusTracker;
var percentage = 1;

function checkStatus() {
    percentage += 1;
    $('.green span').text(percentage + "%");
    $('.green').width(percentage + '%');

    if (percentage == 100) stop();

}
function startProgress(){
    statusTracker = setInterval(checkStatus, 100);
}

function stop() {
    clearInterval(statusTracker);
}
$(document).ready(startProgress);  
</script>

EOD;
```